# NoSuchMethodError при тестировании с помощью Appium

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, appium

Я пытаюсь запустить приложение Facebook и нажать на кнопку "Создать новый аккаунт", используя Appium + эмулятор Андроида Genymotion.
Мой код;

```
public void setup () throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "9");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "192.168.113.101:5555");
    //capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.facebook.katana");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.facebook.account.login.activity.SimpleLoginActivity");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    System.out.println(driver);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);


}
@Test
public void basicTest () {
    driver.navigate().back();
    element =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc=\\\"Create New Facebook Account\\"));
    element.click();
}

@AfterMethod
public void teardown(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

Однако на строке driver = new AndroidDriver выбрасывается исключение (и до basicTest() тест не доходит)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.setElementConverter
(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter;)V
```

При этом в эмуляторе видно, что приложение Facebook запускается  и сразу же после запуска происходит краш теста

Comment: driver = new AndroidDriver... в try/catch засунь. 
Так же проверь правильно ты указал appActivity. Там должен быть значения экрана сплэша, а не экрана логина.

driver.navigate().back(); - что это за строчка ?